# Prevent Google TV to shutdown after 4 hours

Tags: android, kotlin, television

My radio-app on Google/Android TV is automatically shutdown after 4 hours by Google/Android TV.

How can I prevent that?

The solution I found doesn’t work (anymore): https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock#ambient_mode_for_tv

Does anyone have a clue how to solve this?

I tested on a chromecast with Google tv dongle on a HD tv from Samsung. I let my app run during the night in the morning it’s shut down.

Comment: Just making sure you haven't hit the [TV Standby feature](https://source.android.com/docs/core/power/tv-standby) which ignores most wakelocks.

Comment: Thx for your reply :) What do you mean bij “hit”?

Comment: I use a partial_wake_lock (in a background activity) so I understand that the tv standby won’t be activated.

Comment: By 'hit' I mean encountered. If you've tested your app for such standby mode and you don't get the 'is the user still there' prompt for the bad test case., you may want to detail how you are testing as I'm wondering if the TV set is doing the 'shutdown' rather than the dongle/set-top box device. Again you may have already checked/tested but just to clarify what testing you did do.

Comment: Thx for you reply again ;) I start radioNED+ and let it run for some hours. In the morning it's gone. I understand your suggestion that maybe the tv is going to standbye. How are you testing?

Comment: You haven't stated what hardware you have (set-top box / TV model) or how you tested radioNED+ for your desired use case. I am just providing possible paths for investigation. Comments are for readers to request more info from OP which OP should edit their original post with any additional finding/info.

Comment: Thx, for you advice. I added information to the original post :)